# Triple quotient product of a triangle in the Nine Point Circle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Show that the 9-point Circle of a triangle satisfies the cyclic ordered product of segments

$$ \dfrac{BP}{PC}\times \dfrac{CQ} {QA}\times \dfrac{AR}{RB}=1 $$

Show that it could be included in a generalization Menelaus's theorem as a special case of a proposition where the product of ratios is any real number.

[image]

Context was yesterday's  [attempt to find](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032127/is-there-a-curve-intersecting-a-triangle-with-given-transversal-segments-product)  such triple ratio product locus with my following logic for this particular case.

- The circle has equal segments on its sides,  satisfying the generalization
- At foot of perpendicular through Ortho-center the opposite sides are partitioned as:

$$ \dfrac{a \cos B}{b \cos A}\cdot\dfrac{b \cos C}{c \cos B}\cdot \dfrac{c \cos A}{a \cos C} =1$$

which also satisfies the generalization.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the nine-point circle. The three points in the sides are the feet of the altitudes. The altitidues are concurrent and, as such, your triple product is a special case of Ceva's theorem.